# DataMapper first_or_create doesn't work... any ideas why?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Well, I've finally decided that I'm not crazy.  So, that leaves DataMapper.

Here's what I'm doing.  I have a model Msrun which `has 1` Metric.

```
tmp = Msrun.first_or_create # I'll skip the boring details
tmp.metric = Metric.first_or_create( {msrun_id: tmp.id}, {metric_input_file: @metricsfile} )
p tmp.metric # => #<Metric @metric_input_file=nil @msrun_id=1>
tmp.metric.metric_input_file = @metricsfile
p tmp.metric # => #<Metric @metric_input_file=#<Pathname:/home/ryanmt/Dropbox/coding/rails/metrics_site/spec/tfiles/single_metric.txt> @msrun_id=1>
```

So, why doesn't this work?  I'm reading http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy and doing what it shows working.  This has been terribly arduous.  Thanks for any help.

Update:
I still can't figure out what is going on, but to prove I'm not insane...

```
puts Metric.all # => []
tmp.metric = Metric.first_or_create( {msrun_id: tmp.id}, {metric_input_file: @metricsfile} )
puts Metric.all # => [] #??????????????
tmp.metric.metric_input_file = @metricsfile
p tmp.metric # => #<Metric @metric_input_file=#<Pathname:/home/ryanmt/Dropbox/coding/rails/metrics_site/spec/tfiles/single_metric.txt> @msrun_id=1>
tmp.metric.save
puts Metric.all # => [#<Metric @metric_input_file=#<Pathname:/home/ryanmt/Dropbox/coding/rails/metrics_site/spec/tfiles/single_metric.txt> @msrun_id=1>]
```

So, not only is `first_or_create` not delivering on the behavior I expect by reading the source

```
def first_or_create(conditions = {}, attributes = {})
  first(conditions) || create(conditions.merge(attributes))
end
```

but it is also not even creating.

Comment: Looks like it is a "has/belongs_to" that isn't set required: false. I think that will handle the problem. If you care to see the models, I have them posted @ https://github.com/princelab/rails-metric_site/tree/ryan

Comment: This syntax isn't ruby, is it?  It looks like JSON: {msrun_id: tmp.id}

Comment: @TomLianza Totally ruby.  It was introduced in 1.9.  http://www.igvita.com/2011/02/03/new-ruby-19-features-tips-tricks/

Comment: Oooh - nice.  Explains the error I got trying it out on 1.8.7 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm probably missing something here (more of those boring details might help) but if the metric exists, it's metric_input_file shouldn't be updated, i.e., it's only set when new. If you're after updating then you can do

```
.first_or_create(msrun_id: tmp.id).update(metric_input_file: @metricsfile)
```

Or if not hitting the database twice is relevant, then

```
m = Metric.first_or_new(msrun_id: tmp.id)
[set..save..assign]
```

But if it's not being set on *new models*, I don't see what would cause that from the code posted so far, more..?

[UPDATED]

Based on your new code, I'd say this is "a classic case" of a false DM save. I usually add the following line to an initialization section, e.g., application.rb in Rails.

```
DataMapper::Model.raise_on_save_failure = true
```

Unfortunately, the exception raised never tells you why (there's a special place in hell for that choice, right next to people who talk in theaters.) But it's typically one of:

- a slightly incorrect association definition
- a has/belongs_to that isn't "required: false" and isn't set
- putting the wrong datatype into a field, e.g., a string into a decimal
- a validation failing

If you want to post your model definitions, the problem may be spottable there.

Comment: in my reading of the website referenced, it says:
"If the criteria you want to use to query for the resource differ from the attributes you need for creating a new resource, ... ... 

`zoo = Zoo.first_or_create({ :name => 'The Glue Factory' }, { :inception => Time.now })`

This will search for a Zoo named ‘The Glue Factory’ and if it can’t find one, it will return a new Zoo instance with it’s name set to ‘The Glue Factory’ and the inception set to what has been Time.now at the time of execution."

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be obtuse, but I'm not yet sure what you're getting at. The doc is saying a matching instance will be found using the left hash, but if nothing is found, the left and right hash will be merged (with right taking precedence) and used to mass assign the attributes of a new instance that'll also be saved.

Comment: Haha, I like the way you put that.  I'll add that line and post some more code... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, I've seen this call die (like, literally halt all execution) with no error when I was doing a find_or_create that would have created an object that violated the primary key constraint.  This is because the datamapper model was not in sync with the actual database schema.